# QPixmap xAxis Rotation

Tags: qt, rotation, qpixmap, qtranslate

I want to rotate a pixmap from its xAxis, but it just rotates from top left corner.(I want it to be rotated from the center) here is my code:

```
QTransform *X = new QTransform();
X->translate(pixmap().size().width() / 2, pixmap().size().height() / 2);
X->rotate(rtn, Qt::XAxis); //rtn is an angle
setTransform(*X);
```

It seems that the translate method does not change the origin point to the center of my pixmap.
Now I want some help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the problem was that I didn't translate back my transformation after rotate method, this is the appropriate rotation from center on xAxis:

```
setTransform(QTransform().translate(pixmap().size().width() / 2, pixmap().size().height() / 2).rotate(rtn, Qt::XAxis).translate(-pixmap().size().width() / 2, -pixmap().size().height() / 2));
```